# How can I find out what the escape codes my terminal are sending for certain special ones that cat will not show?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, escape-characters, terminal-emulator

I wanted to find out what my terminal is sending for Ctrl+Backspace and Alt+Backspace, the standard way to do this is to run `cat` on the terminal and typing stuff usually works, but with certain output like these, the results are tricky.

I am guessing that Alt+Backspace is sending `\x1b\x7f` (that is, escape backspace) but what's happening if I run `cat` and type Ctrl+V and Alt+Backspace, or just Alt+Backspace, what happens is that the escape will get "typed" and then immediately it is removed with the backspace so it looks like nothing is happening. I only got clued into this once by seeing my computer render a single frame of the `^[` escape being there.

So far I am not sure how to work out what Ctrl+Backspace is sending. it's not Ctrl+W even though both delete a word on the bash prompt, because under `cat` it is doing nothing while  Ctrl+W deletes a word!

Comment: Similar: [Where do I find a list of terminal key codes to remap shortcuts in bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/76566)

Comment: Did you try `cat -v` or `cat -A`?

Comment: @DavidConrad `-v` and `-A` do nothing to improve the situation with these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use this command:

```
showkey -a
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried showkey for a while, neither `showkey` nor `sudo showkey` worked, but `-a` is the magic flag.

Comment: it would just spit back `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`. Might you know what this means?? @egmont

Comment: `showkey` was primarily designed to work on the Linux text console (i.e. Ctrl+Alt+F1 and friends). All options but `-a` look for extra features only available there.

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh`, with:

```
$ STTY='raw -echo min 0 time 40' cat -vte
^[^?
```

Or with `bash`:

```
$ s=$(stty -g); stty raw -echo min 0 time 40; cat -vte; stty "$s"
^[^?
```

You'll see the terminal input raw as it sends it and as rendered by `cat -vte`. Enter nothing for 4 seconds (40 deciseconds) to stop.

You can replace `cat -vte` with `od -An -w1 -tu1 -tx1 -to1 -ta` (assuming GNU `od` or compatible) for instance to see each byte value in decimal, hex, octal or as character.

```
  27
  1b
 033
 esc
 127
  7f
 177
 del
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick elsewhere to show a single character in bash by using `read -rsn1 key && echo "$key" | xxd`. This was 90% of the way there but I was stuck on this for a while because I would just get back 0x1b (Escape), which wasn't the full picture.

Then I changed it to `read -rsn2 key && echo "$key" | xxd` and this scales up to however many characters your escape sequence happens to have, a little bit of experimentation does the trick. So on my terminal I had **both** Ctrl+ and Alt+Backspace mapped to 0x1b, 0x7f (meta-backspace if you will) in the past for convenience reasons. I am going down this path in the first place because I want to configure a new terminal emulator to let me delete words with both combos but only one of them works. The `read -rsn` in bash is a good tool for doing a lower level of output debugging than `cat`.

Comment: You'd want `IFS= read -rsn2 key` for it not to mangle the characters of `$IFS`, and replace `echo` with `printf %s` so a 0x0a byte be not added and backslash not mangled. Note that `read -nx` reads up to x *characters* (not bytes) or up to a newline. Use `LC_ALL=C IFS= read -rsN2` to read 2 bytes (including newline). That still doesn't work for 0 bytes though.